# Why does array_name[1000,1999] have 1600 items?

Tags: ruby

```
numThou = ids.size/1000
for i in 0..numThou
  puts "START:" + (i*1000).to_s
  puts "END:"+ ((i*1000)+999).to_s
  puts "SIZE" + ids[i*1000,(i*1000)+999].size.to_s
end
```

OUTPUTS:

START:0
END:999
SIZE:999

START:1000
END:1999
SIZE:1600

START:2000
END:2999
SIZE:600

How is this 1600 size array possible???

Comment: I think you mean `ids[(i*1000)..(i*1000+999)]`

Comment: You're doing `ids[start,length]` instead of `ids[start..end]`  See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D